# Defining fst and snd with type variables

Tags: python, mypy

I sometimes encounter typing errors when using Haskell-style `fst` and `snd` functions defined in Python as follows:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

a = TypeVar("a")
b = TypeVar("b")


def fst(x: tuple[a, b]) -> a:
    """Return the first element of a pair."""
    return x[0]


def snd(x: tuple[a, b]) -> b:
    """Return the second element of a pair."""
    return x[1]
```

As an example, running the following through [mypy](https://www.mypy-lang.org/) succeeds:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator


def f(xs: Iterable[tuple[str, int]]) -> Iterator[int]:
    """Return second element of string-integer pairs."""
    return map(snd, xs)
```

However, this function:

```py
def g(xs: Iterable[tuple[str, int]]) -> list[int]:
    """Return second element of string-integer pairs."""
    return list(map(snd, xs))
```

results in the following mypy error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Callable[[Tuple[a, b]], b]"; expected "Callable[[Tuple[str, int]], b]"  [arg-type]
```

What is the cause of this error?  Are `fst` and `snd` defined incorrectly?

Comment: The cause of this error, I'm pretty sure, is expecting Python's type hints (as processed by a third-party tool that is free to make up its own specification, while those hints have *no effect at runtime* except to set some `__annotations__` attributes) to have the power of a static inferred type system in a language that is consciously built around that system from the ground up.

Comment: This looks like a mypy bug - the `return` statement of `f` has no type error, but the `map` expression in any other context does. Reproduced at `mypy-play.net`: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=27e30aa9e1a290d9b0115ec71d718702

Comment: `mypy` fails to handle `map` correctly: equivalent generator `(snd(x) for x in xs)` is revealed as `Generator[int, None, None]` (compatible with `Iterator[int]`), and listcomp of the same form is `list[int]`. However, `map` gives weird errors for some reason. Here's the relevant [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2389) - I added your example to that issue, because it is not in line with "just add annotation" resolution.